# Como puedo otener los datos del JSONArray?

Tags: ionic, ionic4, ionic-framework

estoy tratando de leer los datos de un servicio que estan dentro del JSONArray, cuando disparo el evento del boton me da un error de syntax del JSON (ERROR SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: )
Estoy utilisando ionic v5 , que estoy bastante nuevo en el tema 
la repuesta de mi servicio

```
{"Error":"0","Datos":[{"nombre":"Widmaer","usuario":"widy","estado":"Abonado"}]}
```

ahi esta mi codigo lo que intente hacer depues de leer muchos articulos en la web

```
 this.http.get('mi_url').subscribe(res=>{
 this.response =JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(res))
 console.log("Result: "+ this.response.Datos.nombre);
if(this.response.Error==0){
this.route.navigate(['/principal']) //Si la conexcion es exitosa , direcciona en la pagina principal
} else{
  this.Toast();// Error de Conexxion
}
```

quiero obtener el nombre y cargarlo en un  de la pagina principal.htlm

```
  <ion-label >Welcome :{{....}} </ion-label>
```

Answer (score 1):

No se si te servira, pero creo que el error es que estas tratando de leer un array como un objeto.
tene ne cuenta que datos es un array y no un objeto.
deberias llamarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
 console.log("Result: "+ this.response.Datos[0].nombre);
```